# How to select certain cells within a table via jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, selector

I'm building a clone of how Google Drive inserts tables into documents. Basically, there is a grid of squares which allow you to select how many rows and columns you want. By hovering, you can select a group of row/columns starting from the top left corner, down to your pointer. I can't seem to get the highlighting working correctly because of the crazy selector needed.

This is what I have now:

```
$('.row-add:lt(' + hoveredRows + ') .cell-add:lt(' + hoveredCols + ')').addClass('cell-highlight');
```

Which states "find rows less than the user's selected number of rows, and then within that, select columns less than the user's selected number of columns".

The problem is that it's only working within the first row, I presume because the index of each cell doesn't reset just because it's in a new row.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kthornbloom/jLrna0fz/1/

Related Code:

```js
$('.cell-add').hover(
    function () {
        
        // How many rows/cols have you selected?
        var hoveredCols = $(this).index() + 1,
            hoveredRows = $(this).parent().index() + 1;
        
        // Remove old highlighting
        $('.cell-highlight').removeClass('cell-highlight');
        
        // Update the text hint
        $('.table-dimension-result').html(hoveredRows + ' x ' + hoveredCols);
        
        // Add Highlighting to selected squares from top left to cursor
        $('.row-add:lt(' + hoveredRows + ') .cell-add:lt(' + hoveredCols + ')').addClass('cell-highlight');
        
}, function () {
    // Remove old highlighting
    $('.cell-highlight').removeClass('cell-highlight');
});
```

```css
.table-dimension {
    padding:10px;
    font-size:0;
    line-height:0;
}
.table-dimension-result {
    margin-top:10px;
    font-size:14px;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    line-height:1.4em;
}
.row-add {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.cell-add {
    display:inline-block;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    border:5px solid #fff;
    background:#ccc
}
.cell-highlight {
    border:5px solid #fff;
    background:#ec4b22;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="table-dimension">
    <div class="row-add">
        <div class="cell-add"></div>
        <div class="cell-add"></div>
        <div class="cell-add"></div>
        <div class="cell-add"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-add">
        <div class="cell-add"></div>
        <div class="cell-add"></div>
        <div class="cell-add"></div>
        <div class="cell-add"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-add">
        <div class="cell-add"></div>
        <div class="cell-add"></div>
        <div class="cell-add"></div>
        <div class="cell-add"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-add">
        <div class="cell-add"></div>
        <div class="cell-add"></div>
        <div class="cell-add"></div>
        <div class="cell-add"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-dimension-result">0x0</div>
</div>

Column highlighting works,<br> row highlighting does not.
```

How can I modify the selector to also work with the rows? I have tried the code above, as well as using an each statement which didn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `lt` isn't base on child position, but on the number of element it return. You really need to use a selector which is based on children position. You can achieve that with a mix of `':not'` and `':nth-child(1n+' + (hoveredCols+1) + ')'`. Just like that :

```
$('.row-add:lt(' + hoveredRows + ') .cell-add:not(:nth-child(1n+' + (hoveredCols+1) + '))').addClass('cell-highlight');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jLrna0fz/3/)